# Template editor not applied when using Ajax for partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a template editor, `Currency.cshtml` like this:

```
@model decimal?
...
string value =
// Some calculations that returns value formatted as currency

Currency: @value<br/>
@Html.TextBox("", value, attributes)
```

I have a view which uses this template like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Amount.Value, "Currency", someAdditionalViewData)
```

When this view is rendered as a partial directly inside another view, the result is as expected: both the text, and the editor show the formatted variable "value", like so:

```
Currency: 1.223,18   <== well formatted
[         1.223,18]  <== this is the input type=text, well formatted
```

However, if I get the view using Ajax (`Ajax.ActionLink`), I get the firs part formatted, but the second one unformatted, like so:

```
Currency: 1.223,18   <== well formatted
[          1223.18]  <== this is the input type=text, not formatted!!
```

Any idea why this can be going on? Should I change the final `@Html.TextBox("", value, attributes)` in my template for something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason, but after investigating for some time, I can assure that the final call to `@Html.TextBox("", value, attributes)`, on an Ajax request behaves in a different way than on a PartialView render.

In a PartialView render, it creates the desired input element, with the provided formatted value. However, in an ajax request, it looks up for info on the model and creates its own version of the textbox, including the unobstrusive validation attributes and so on.

The only way to solve this problem is not to use the `TextBox` method, but create an input writing it directly with a `TagBuilder`. Pay attention to the way of getting the Id and name for the input element.

```
@{
string value = ... // Format as desired

// Create the required attributes
// NOTE: HtmlAttributes is simply a custom "fluent" attribute builder, 
// inherited from IDictionay<string,object>
var attributes = HtmlAttributes.Empty
    .Add("type", "text")
    .Add("value", value) // formatted value
    .Add("id", ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(""))
    .Add("name", ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))
    .AddStyle("text-align", "right");

// You can add extra attributes, i.e. unobtrusive validation, provided by user...
var extraAttibutes = ...
attributes.Merge(extraAttributes);

// Use the tag builder to create the input
TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("input");
foreach (var attribute in attributes)
{
    tb.Attributes.Add(attribute.Key, attribute.Value.ToString());
}
var textBox = tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

// Then, either write it directly to the writer...
ViewContext.Writer.Write(textBox);
}
@* ...or use Html.Raw *@
@Html.Raw(textBox)
```

Of course, there are a lot of details omitted (how to get unobtrusive or any other extra attributes for the tag and so on). The best soultion would be to discover why the behavior changes from a "complete" render and an ajax request render. All the View metadata looks exactly the same, but works in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a partialview that used an editortemplate which worked when initially loading the page. However when using ajax to call for the partial the editortemplate wasn't used.

For me turned out I had to move it to a different folder:

**From** 
*Views/[Controllername]/EditorTemplates*

**To**
*Views/Shared/EditorTemplates*